What is going on with my psn account?
So someone hacked my psn account and was able to buy stuff using my phone number but didn't have to pay at the time they bought it so the bills racked up for me I reported this to Sony this was a good 7 or 8 months ago. Since then I have not been able to get into my psn account. I did call Sony to have the account suspended so this couldn't happen again but a month later when I called to have it unsuspended they said the account was never closed. Yet u cannot get into my account. I try logging in or changing the password and it says "the connection to the server has timed out". But tbh it's said this for 2 years so this has happened before this whole drama. But I tried changing my birthday as a way of changing password and it says my birthday is wrong even tho I have email proof from Sony that it is right.(gkt an email in 2o23 saying I'm now 18 u can upgrade my account blah blah blah. I have no way of getting back into my account and Sony don't seem to care or try to do anything about it and I have spent money on that account. 1. Can u sue them?
And 2. Can I get my account back
Oh and I think someone might be on my account cuz I have recently got into my email associated with the psn account and the account has added a bunch of people on call of duty since I was last on it.

Hey, welcome to Arcade. First of all - we can’t give legal advice. If you want to try to sue Sony, you have to do that through your own lawyers (and it almost definitely won’t be worth it). Your question could also be edited to be more readable, which could help you get answers.
